# Font Size and Font Family in Nokia QT

Tags: qt, symbian, s60

Which font is supported by the Nokia phones(s60)? I used the Arial,Arial Narrow but I could not see clearly.( I'm developing apps based on the nokia qt sdk in mac 10.6)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [QFontDatabase](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qfontdatabase.html) to query the fonts available on your device.